# How do I indicate that a method never returns a null using code contracts?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, code-contracts, microsoft-contracts

How do I indicate that a method never returns a null? Currently this is my code.

Line 19 gets an Ensures not proven message, even though CreateFunction assumes that the result is not nothing.

```
1         <Pure()> Public Function CreateFunction(Of TArg1, TArg2, TResult)(ByVal body As Func(Of Expression, Expression, BinaryExpression)) As Func(Of TArg1, TArg2, TResult)   
2             Contract.RequiresAlways(body IsNot Nothing)   
3             Contract.Assume(Contract.Result(Of Func(Of TArg1, TArg2, TResult))() IsNot Nothing)   
4   
5             Dim arg1 = Expression.Parameter(GetType(Integer), "arg1")   
6             Dim arg2 = Expression.Parameter(GetType(Integer), "arg2")   
7   
8   
9             Dim temp = Expression.Lambda(body(arg1, arg2), arg1, arg2)   
10             Contract.Assume(temp IsNot Nothing)   
11             Return DirectCast(temp.Compile, Global.System.Func(Of TArg1, TArg2, TResult))   
12         End Function  
13   
14         <Pure()> Public Function Add() As Func(Of T, T, T)   
15             Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result(Of Func(Of T, T, T))() IsNot Nothing)   
16   
17             Dim temp = CreateFunction(Of T, T, T)(AddressOf Expression.AddChecked)   
18             Return temp   
19         End Function
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does

```
Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result() != null);
```

work?  Basically, I'd try paring it down till you find the simplest case that doesn't work as you'd expect and go from there.

-- MarkusQ

Comment: I used the same construct, I think it's correct. Too bad the OP does not reply.

Comment: It's VB, so it would be `Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result(Of Func(Of TArg1, TArg2, TResult))() IsNot Nothing)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `Assume` in `CreateFunction` to an `Ensures`. After that you should be okay. Remember, `Assume` is for internal assumptions in order to help the static checker locally. They are not visible from other methods. Only `Requires` and `Ensures` are cross-method contracts.